# Authentication if the user is Logged in or Not?

Tags: javascript

I am new in using the .htaccess file. 
I am learning to create my very first dashboard and can't even know how to protect it from hackers or any other threat. I don't know how to authenticate if the user is actually logged in or he/she redirected only using the search bar to redirect to the main page.
Now, I learned that the HTACCESS file can authenticate if the user is actually logged in, and/or not even he/she tries to redirect using the search bar, it will show the 404 error page.

But now, I have seen this sample .htaccess file.
http://www.htaccess-guide.com/how-to-use-htaccess/

and can't substitute the right path of every HTML.

any help would be much appreciated.

This is the htaccess file

```
AuthName "Member's Area Name"
AuthUserFile /path/to/password/file/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 /error_pages/401.html
AddHandler server-parsed .html
```

Thank you and Regards,

> **EDIT**

As I have said Above, I am new in web development And trying to develop my very first dashboard. Currently, I want to authenticate if the user is actually logged in or not. For now, I have this code that will check the sessionStorage if there is more than 1 value. If not, It will redirect to the login page of the dashboard.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    AESDecrypt();
})

function AESDecrypt() {
    if (sessionStorage.length <= 1) {
        window.sessionStorage.clear();
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    } else {
        var userInfo = sessionStorage.getItem("AppHunt");
        var decryptUser = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(userInfo, AESuserDataEncryptions.AESPASSWORD);
        var strUserFullName = decryptUser.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        var strUserFullName = strUserFullName.toString();
        validateUSERAccount(strUserFullName);
    }
}

function validateUSERAccount(decryptedUser) {
    var value = "{'user':" + decryptedUser
                + "}";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../WebService/wsIndex.asmx/ValidateUserAccount',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: value,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            var cells = eval("(" + response.d + ")");
            if (cells.length <= 0) {
                window.location.href = "login.html";
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

There is no Problem in the code below, But I want to know if there is a more effective solution to redirect the user in the login page if he/she does not logged in to any account.

Comment: If your dashboard is in `/dashboard/` then you put this .htaccess file there and it will require the users to authenticate. if your dashboard uses another authenticate method already (for example, server-side scripting and sessions), then there's no need to user another authentication layer, but you need to check the session in every page.

Comment: @Capsule How to check the session sir in every page? Currently my Only code that is working is, checking the session storage if it has the same value.. and if not then it will redirect the user to login page

Comment: Hard to tell without any code. What are you trying to solve exactly? Seems like you already have a working solution. If what you are currently doing doesn't work, post your code, what you tried so far, and the expected result.

Comment: @Capsule . I already edit the question sir.

Comment: Well, you need to implement the same kind of logic on the server side. Anyone that disables Javascript would be able to access anything. If you decide to use the htaccess approach then you don't need to implement any other logic but you will have to rely on the browser auth dialog and not a custom login page (there's also a way to tie things together but it's getting complicated, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html)

Comment: @Capsule, but i want to use a custom login page, is there a way sir to implement the apache in custom page?

Comment: Oh so you stopped reading after I said it was getting complicated?

Comment: @Capsule, I found out that there is a possible way to do the authentication of a user on the server side. Also, I read the link you had given me. Thank you sir. I learn something new. God Bless. I will use the apache, on the future. Thanks again sir.